# How can I display the grand total SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a graph in SSRS and need to display the amount separated by status, but also need to display the total value, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by status, then right click the status group and select "add total".
Depending on how many group levels you have, you may need to experiment with precisely where to add the total.

Answer (score 0):

There is grouping and that's the best way, if not the only way, to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do as following:
Sum(CInt(Fields!TestValue.Value))
 or Sum(CInt(Fields!DollarAmountOfCheck.Value),"DataSet1") 
sometime when data is coming through WCF service, it does not accept Sum() function. but this works fine in that case.